# New object window ; is it possible to change locations of the fields

Tags: object, new

New object window ; is it possible to change locations of the fields

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While viewing an RMA Request record, click on ⚙️, Edit Object, Page Layouts, click on the Layout name, and then adjust the fields as you desire. Please note that this will affect the new, view, and edit pages equally; you cannot adjust only the "new record" page.